# Getting object variable or With block variable not set

Tags: excel, vba

This script goes through all the selected sheets and inserts 10 blank rows at the top. It then should export these sheets and save the `WS` name into a `csv` format. However I seem to be getting the error `Getting object variable or With Block variable not set`.

I tried a few things but so far no success.

```
Sub Insert_Rows_Loop()
Dim CurrentSheet As Object
Dim WS As Worksheet
Dim path As String


path = ActiveWorkbook.path & "\" & Left(ActiveWorkbook.Name, InStr(ActiveWorkbook.Name, ".") - 1)


' Loop through all selected sheets.
For Each CurrentSheet In ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets
    ' Insert 10 rows at top of each sheet.
    CurrentSheet.Range("a1:a10").EntireRow.Insert

    'With ws
            WS.SaveAs Filename:=path & "_" & WS.Name & ".csv", FileFormat:=xlCSV, CreateBackup:=False
        'End With


Next CurrentSheet
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Dan, When the selected WS are exported, is there a way to keep the insertion of the 10 rows intact, for eg when I selected the worksheets, the macro goes through and inserted the ten blank row however when I export and check them I don't see the insertion of the top 10 blank rows in.

Comment: Just because you declare WS a worksheet, doesn't mean Excel knows which worksheet you're talking about.  Trying setting the worksheet to a specific worksheet and see if that gets you closer.

Answer (score 1):

While running a macro, I came across an error: Run-time error '429': ActiveX component can't create object.

Clicking on Debug will show me an error: "Object variable or With block variable not set".

The issue was with `ThisWorkbook`. I replaced it with `Application.ThisWorkbook` and it resolved the issue. So, please try using `Application.ActiveWorkbook`